# Como somar coluna no MySQL usando SUM deixando coluna disponível para exibição

Tags: mysql

Preciso somar algumas colunas no MySQL, usar a soma para fazer uma média e deixar as colunas disponíveis para exibição em um relatório, tentei fazer a soma na consulta no MySQL mas não deu certo, vou tentar explicar melhor com uma imagem do meu banco, tentei fazer a soma usando `SUM` assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O `sql` dessa imagem está assim:

```
SELECT af.idAfericao,
       af.data, af.produto,
       af.deterUmidade,
       af.deterVal1,
       af.deterVal2,
       af.deterVal3,
       af.deterVal4,
       af.deterVal5,
       SUM(af.deterValMedia) AS SomaVarMedia,
       af.modeloDestilador,
       SUM(af.resultadoDestilacao) AS SomaDestilacao,
       SUM(af.diferenca) AS SomaDiferenca,
       af.ativo,
       cu.descricao,
       cc.nome
  FROM comUnidade cu,
       afericaoAgricola af,
       comColaborador cc
 WHERE af.idUnidade = 6
   AND af.idUnidade = cu.idUnidade
   AND af.ativo = 1
   AND af.classificador = cc.idColaborador
   AND af.data BETWEEN '2016-02-10'
   AND '2016-02-16'
   AND af.deterUmidade='Dickey-John'
   AND af.produto='Soja'
   AND af.modeloDestilador='CA 50'
GROUP BY af.idAfericao
ORDER BY af.data DESC
```

Gostaria de poder ter o resultado das colunas para exibir em meu relatório, mas também preciso da soma de cada coluna para fazer uma média.

O modelo do relatório é esse:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Fazer uma subquery na linha do select apenas para calcular a soma e média te atende?

Comment: Você quer que a soma fique dividida em cada linha? Ou seja, para que esse campo da Soma seja exibido somente na última linha do relatório nos totais?

Comment: Olá @Ipacheco, valeu pela resposta.

Comment: Olá @gabrieloliveira, preciso de uma soma das colunas exatamente como você disse.

Comment: Qual é o software que você está usando para a geração dos relatórios? Eu posso estar enganado mas em termos de consulta você não teria como trazer uma linha diferente das outras, elas contêm os mesmos campos. Nesse caso você está precisando de uma linha de totais, que geralmente é feita na aplicação que manipula os dados. Você queria esse resultado somente com uma consulta MySQL?

Comment: Estou usando do Dreamweaver CS6 @gabrieloliveira, você quer dizer que seria melhor fazer a soma pelo Dreamweaver?

Comment: Mas esse relatório estará disponível em alguma aplicação web? Ou você só precisa gerá-lo uma vez?

Comment: É gerado sempre que o usuário precisar @gabrieloliveira.

Comment: Então, mas você está construindo uma aplicação para ler esses dados e gerar o relatório? Em PHP?

Comment: Se quer uma linha com SUM só no final, use UNION para juntar o SELECT da listagem com o SELECT do SUM. Use as mesmas condições no WHERE de ambas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por alguma razão que desconheço e por ser um código legado, a tabela `afericaoAgricola` tem os campos `deterValMedia`, `resultadoDestilacao` e `diferenca` definidos como `DataType` `VARCHAR(45)`, não tinha me atentado para tal detalhe.
Para resolver o meu problema fiz o seguinte, tive converter os valores armazenados nos referidos campos trocando a vírgula por ponto, dessa forma:

`SELECT IdAfericao, CAST( REPLACE(afericaoAgricola.deterValMedia,',','.') as DECIMAL(18,2)) 
  FROM afericaoAgricola
 WHERE afericaoAgricola.IdAfericao <= 20`

Dessa forma consegui os valores corretamente.

Para realizar a soma fiz assim:

`SELECT idAfericao, SUM(CAST( replace(afericaoAgricola.deterValMedia,',','.') as DECIMAL(18,2)) )
 FROM afericaoAgricola
WHERE afericaoAgricola.idAfericao <= 20`

Com isso consegui que os valores ficassem corretos.